# Purpose of setting two environment variables in Webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

What does it mean if you set two [environment variables in Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/environment-variables/)? For example `dev` and `build` variables [here](https://github.com/krasimir/webpack-library-starter/blob/d26234381f34dfc603b2e09c8f6a14bbd2d37d13/package.json#L7).

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --env dev && webpack --env build && npm run test",
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that you want to process files in "two modes". At first, webpack processes files in `dev` mode and after that in `build` mode.